# customize a console.log with css styling and with arbitrary arguments

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have checked the google dev tools for console (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console), and know that `'%c'` can apply CSS style rules to output string.

Here is my problem:
I want to write a functon `redLog(msg, regExp)`, for example `redLog('Page1, Page2', /\d/g)` outputs the same text and style with `console.log('Page%c1%c, Page%c2%c', 'color:red', 'color:black', 'color:red', 'color:black')`, but the arbitrary css `string('color:red', 'color:black', 'color:red', 'color:black')` troubles me.
My recent code snippet is listed as follows(This is my first experience of posting a question in English, i don't know for sure that my problem has made it clear to you guys.):

```js
// redLog('Page1, Page2', /\d/g)
// function as console.log('Page%c1%c, Page%c2%c', 'color:red', 'color:black', 'color:red', 'color:black')

// msg: the output string
// regExp: when any characters match the regExp, red it
function redLog(msg, regExp) {
  var cssStr = '';

  if (msg && regExp) {
    msg = msg.replace(regExp, '%c$&%c'); // '$&' inserts the matched substring.
    console.log(msg); // i cannot determine the cssStr
  }
  else {
    console.log(msg);
  }
}
```

Comment: Writing your question completely in bold does neither help to make it better readable nor does it make your question more important. **writing everything in bold is more like shouting** SIMILAR AS IF YOU WOULD WRITE EVERYTHING IN UPPERCASES.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is really complex because `console.log` needs a css string argument for every `%c` in your message. But since you do that dynamically, you cannot hard code your arguments for `console.log`, what leads to the problem, that you need to call `console.log` with an array of arguments. For this problem the `.apply` method can be used:

```
console.log.apply(console, args);
```

But to use this, you need to set up an array for the arguments:

```
var args = [msg];
```

and fill it with the needed amount of css styles, which is a little complicated, because you need to find all the appearances of `%c` in your message and toggle between two (or more if you want) css styles:

```
var helpString = msg;
var toggleNextString = false;
while (helpString.indexOf("%c") != -1) {
    if (!toggleNextString) args.push(cssStrNew);
    else args.push(cssStrStandard);
    toggleNextString = !toggleNextString;
    helpString = helpString.substr(helpString.indexOf("%c") + 2);
}
```

Note: I used two strings for the standard log css and for the color red.

Putting all of this together, the function looks like this:

```
function redLog(msg, regExp) {
    var cssStrNew = 'color: red;';
    var cssStrStandard = 'color: black';

    if (msg && regExp) {
        msg = msg.replace(regExp, '%c$&%c');
        var args = [msg];
        var helpString = msg;
        var toggleNextString = false;
        while (helpString.indexOf("%c") != -1) {
            if (!toggleNextString) args.push(cssStrNew);
            else args.push(cssStrStandard);
            toggleNextString = !toggleNextString;
            helpString = helpString.substr(helpString.indexOf("%c") + 2);
        }
        console.log.apply(console, args);
    } else {
        msg = "%c" + msg
        console.log(msg, cssStrNew);
    }
}
```

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjw7ke0o/2/)

IMPORTANT: `%c` doesn't work within all browsers (for Firefox you can use Firebug) (afaik)

Comment: :) that's what I thought it should look like but in not into javascript :)

Comment: The `%c` should work with all current _WebKit_ / _Blink_  based browsers (Chrome, Safari, Opera). But I never tested it in IE.

Comment: @t.niese I changed the note

Answer (score 0):

Well try this, although you need still work on the regExp. This is just a tip ( how to display your message with a color ) , your question is more complex and bit messy. You trying to add several parameters into your function, you should try use 1 parameter color and make an array of it. Inside the function you would organize it properly for your needs.

Edit2. Outcome is Page**1**, Page%c2 , where (%c2 doesn't want to get bold here) **bold** stands for blue. As I know there is no closing bracket for %c, so you need to explode parameter 1 by a comma (,) -> assign to table and lunch console.log foreach element in array.

```
if (msg && regExp) {
    msg = msg.replace(regExp, '%c$&'); // '$&' inserts the matched substring.

    console.log(""+msg+"", cssStr);
  }
```

---

```
  function redLog(msg, regExp) {
      var cssStr = 'color: blue; font-size: x-large';

      if (msg && regExp) {
        msg = msg.replace(regExp, '%c$&%c'); // '$&' inserts the matched substring.

        console.log("%c"+msg+"", cssStr);
      }
      else {
        console.log(msg);
      }
    }
     redLog('Page1, Page2', /\d/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

For every `%c` there needs to be a style. In your case, if you only want the numbers to be highlighted then you could make your function generic by passing the highlight and normal colors as parameters as well:

```
function colorLog(string, regexp, style, normalStyle) {
    var msg = string.replace(regexp, function (s) {
        return "%c" + s + "%c"
    });
    var css = [msg];
    var occurances = string.match(regexp).length;
    while (css.length < occurances * 2) css = css.concat([style, normalStyle]);
    console.log.apply(console, css);
}
```

And then you call it like this:

```
colorLog('Page-1, 23rd-Page, Page-3', /\d+/g, 'color:blue', 'color:black');
```

The idea is to create an array out of strings and flatten it out using `apply`. You could further simplify your call by passing only the color names and create the style string inside the function.

You can do a multi-line with different colors by making just a minimal changes.

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/ydLmtm3a/4/***

.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much, @Markai and @abhitalks, "console.log.apply(console, args)" is indeed the key to my problem.
Below is my solution inspired by Markai.

```js
function colorLog(str, regExp, style, normalStyle) {
  if (str && regExp) {
    var css = [],
        i = 1, // css[0] is reserved for msg
        msg = str.replace(regExp, function (m) {
          css[i++] = style;
          css[i++] = normalStyle;
          return '%c' + m + '%c';
        });

    css[0] = msg;

    console.log.apply(console, css);
  }
  else {
    console.log(str);
  }
}

function redLog(str, regExp) {
  colorLog(str, regExp, 'color:red', 'color:black');
}

redLog('Page-1, 23rd-Page, Page-3', /\d+/g);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сan even shorter:

```
string='';//random string for painting
//color classifier - 6 types of non-breaking space:
for(let i=120;i--;) string+=`${'\u180E\u200B\u200C\u200D\u2060\uFEFF'[6*Math.random()^0]}${'+-0'[3*Math.random()^0]}`;

css = [string];//preparing an array for spread
//we are returning the replaced string in css[0], using as the second argument .replace() a arrow function (which writes to a global variables):
css[0] = css[0].replace(/(\u180E[\+\-0])|(\u200B[\+\-0])|(\u200C[\+\-0])|(\u200D[\+\-0])|(\u2060[\+\-0])|(\uFEFF[\+\-0])/g, (match, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) => {
    if ($1) {css.push('color: blue;')}
    if ($2) {css.push('color: red;')}
    if ($3) {css.push('color: green;')}
    if ($4) {css.push('color: yellow;')}
    if ($5) {css.push('color: magenta;')}
    if ($6) {css.push('color: cyan;')}
return`%c${match}`});//so that neighboring '%c' do not overlap
console.log(...css);
```

Here we do not use flags and explicit loops. We use only one function. You can write instructions of multiple choice for global variable css[] (like a 'switch...case') on one line:

```
css.push(`color: ${'blue red green yellow magenta cyan'.split(' ')[Math.log2(+('0b'+[$6, $5, $4, $3, $2, $1].map(e=>+!!e).join('')))]};`);
```

– in the first step array of regex capturing groups transformed at bit field, further we find log<sub>2</sub>(*field*), which is the position in the array of colors at RPN. So length of the function is 5 lines, not counting the first 2 lines containing 'random()' for test (which you can also write on one line using recursion:

```
css = [(s=>(f = (i, recursion =_=>(s+=`${'\u180E\u200B\u200C\u200D\u2060\uFEFF'[6*Math.random()^0]}${'+-0'[3*Math.random()^0]}`, f(--i)))=>!i? s :recursion())(120))('')];
```

).

Thus, we can use in theory max up to 6! = 720 colors, i.e. you need `&h100`<sup>3</sup>/6! = 23302 groups for a standard palette with a depth of 24 bits.

**Open a console** by browser on this page and run:

```js
(a => (a.type = 'text/javascript', a.id = 'demo_console', a.innerHTML = 
`const css = [(s=>(f = (i, recursion =_=>(s+=\`$\{'\u180E\u200B\u200C\u200D\u2060\uFEFF'[6*Math.random()^0]}$\{'+-0'[3*Math.random()^0]}\`, f(--i)))=>!i? s :recursion())(120))('')];
css[0] = css[0].replace(/(\u180E[\+\-0])|(\u200B[\+\-0])|(\u200C[\+\-0])|(\u200D[\+\-0])|(\u2060[\+\-0])|(\uFEFF[\+\-0])/g, (match, $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6)=>\{
 css.push(\`color: $\{'blue red green yellow magenta cyan'.split(' ')[Math.log2(+('0b'+[$6, $5, $4, $3, $2, $1].map(e=>+!!e).join('')))]};\`);
return\`%c$\{match}\`});
console.log(...css);`
))(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(document.createElement('script')))
```